# Spring Boot unable to render (very) simple index.jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I am trying to render an html .jsp with just an h1 tag in it...feels like it should work but it doesnt.

**How can I get the index.jsp file to render into my browser?** Please help!

I'm using:
Maven 3.5.4
Java 1.8.0_181
STS Version: 3.9.5.RELEASE

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I am successfully logging to route being hit but the index.jsp is not being read.

```
package com.coding.test1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class Test1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test1Application.class, args);
    }
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("+++++hit main+++++++");
        return "index.jsp";
    }
}
```

logs

> +++++hit main+++++++

Browser shows

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Sep 10 20:49:47 PDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
```

> Blockquote

pom.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.coding.test1</groupId>
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>test1</name>
    <description>test1</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Folder Structure
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/477766353709826054/488922584260411392/unknown.png
(not enough rep to post picture of my directory)

EDIT: 
Adding ServletInitializer.java

```
package com.coding.test1;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Test1Application.class);
    }

}
```

Logging res: https://github.com/GNouchi/SO-52268550/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Did you try to remove @Controller in package com.coding.test1?

Comment: Change this `return "index.jsp"` to `return "index"`

Comment: @Hana just tried that and the result is it does not hit the route.

Comment: @NicholasK just tried that, and it does still hit the route, but I am not using a suffix of .jsp so ultimately that may not work?

Comment: Show us what the class `ServletInitializer` does in your project. The solution proposed by @NicholasK should work.

Comment: @Val14720 Are you running the project within an external Tomcat? Or are you using the embedded one? Also, can you try adding `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` as a property and provide the logs when you try to open http://localhost:8080?

Comment: @g00glen00b logging linked at the bottom, I am a newbie to java in general so I'm not really sure if its external or embed tomcat, though the tutorial for my bootcamp is telling explicitly to ensure dependencies for **tomcat-embed-jasper and jstl**

Comment: @Val14720 I'm guessing you're running it as a normal Spring boot or Java application within Eclipse, if that's the case, then you're using the embedded one. For the logs, it looks like it isn't able to find `index.jsp`, my guess is that Eclipse isn't properly registering your project as a web project, and thus, the `src/main/webapp` folder isn't picked up. Try to run your project by executing `mvn spring-boot:run` on the command line. If that works, then there's something with your Eclipse configuration, I'm no expert there, but perhaps you should try to enable the web facet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this , and it works for me .

```
    <!-- This is a web application -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP, 
        tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, no idea why -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: just replaced all of my dependencies with what you have in a clean build of the proj , unfortunately it does not work...I'm wondering if this could be an installation error...though its weird that its hitting the route correctly

Comment: Remove all mvn dependencies from local storage then update maven.. Maybe maven dependencies installed not correctly and jars are corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in your application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

And change

`return "index.jsp"` to

`return "index"`

Also, as a side note I would advice you to move your `@controller` to another class.

Comment: Ah sorry responded to your comment a bit early. I did try that with the suffix and also no cigar, though the route is still successfully being entered.

Comment: Strange, try creating a separate class for your controller and clean build the project.

Comment: made a new workspace->new project-> the whole shabang to no avail...same result.

Comment: One more thing you could try, instead of returning a `String` try to return an object of `ModelAndView`. You should then set the view to your `index.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

**This was an installation error.** Not sure which steps exactly fixed it but I'll outline in case anyone wants to follow.

- Deleted .m2 from C:\users{username}
- Deleted apache-maven-3.5.4
- Removed Path for maven  Removed JAVA_HOME Download fresh copy of the
  zip from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
- Unzip into desired
  folder.
- Add path to {folder structure}/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin
- Add JAVA_HOME pointing to jdk folder (not bin) under SYSTEM VARIABLES
  (not user variables) - *was previously user variables*
- Open Eclipse in a brand new workspace remake Spring Starter project to test basic render of html page

Huge thank you to everyone on this thread! Helped me get out of a dark place :).

EDIT: styling list

Answer (score 0):

Actually you messed up in main class. First write your main class like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Test1Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

   @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Test1Application.class);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now create a project structure like https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWMAW.png

Now create a  package under `com.coding.test1` Now write a controller on that new package

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String gotoHome() {
        return "index";
    }
```

Now write `application.properties` like

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

And I thing this dependency is not needed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can you relink the folder structure?  right now @Controller has an error that it is not an annotation type.

Comment: (1) Extending `SpringBootServletInitializer` is only necessary if he plans on running it on an external Tomcat. He didn't say that he does. (2) `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is not necessary since `@SpringBootApplication` already implies that. (3) While a separate controller class is a good idea, it isn't necessary. (4) The file is named `application.properties`, not `application.property`.